# how adjust legend labels in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

Hi there I'm not an expert with R and try to learn few things,

I wrote this piece of code for getting an histogram out of an Excel file

```
library(readxl)
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)
library(reshape2)


## excel1 <- read_excel("/media/mat/Extreme SSD/TheUniversityOfFerrara/2°Year/vcf_output-HG002againstHGDP00704_R.xlsx") # swap for overall variants distribution
excel2 <- read_excel("/media/mat/Extreme SSD/TheUniversityOfFerrara/2°Year/vcf_output-HG002againstHGDP00704-sites_R.xlsx")

df <- data.frame(excel2)
df <- melt(df, id.vars='record')

## names(df)[1] <- 'variant_type' # swap for overall variants distribution
names(df)[1] <- 'site_type'
names(df)[2] <- 'sample'

## df$variant_type <- as.character(df$variant_type) # swap for overall variants distribution
## df$variant_type <- factor(df$variant_type, levels=c('records', 'SNPs', 'indels', 'multiallelic-sites', 'others')) # swap for overall variants distribution

ggplot(df, aes(x=site_type, y=value, fill=sample)) + geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge', width=.4) + theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face='bold.italic', hjust = 0.5), legend.position='bottom', legend.title=element_blank()) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('#006BF7', '#BE90D4')) + ggtitle('HG002-HGDP00704_Giraffe Variant Call')
```

The plot generated by `ggplot` is the following
[image]
What I would need is to add a label above HG002 and HGDP00704 that says EUR and AME, respectively. I'm aware I removed the original label, that is because it was not relevant. Is there a way to do it? I was thinking about a table.
Let me know!

Thanks in advance.

P.S. if the code is not good and you have any suggestion, please feel free to tell me

Comment: Please add the output of `dput(melt(df, id.vars='record'))` into the question to make it reproducible. Perhaps have a look at these links: [MRE] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This is not a histogram!  This a bar or column chart.'

Comment: @Peter & Dave2e Noted, thanks for the feedback. Sorry for the confusion about the graph type. However, I managed to sort it out, thanks anyway!